# How to setup environment files for dev, local and prod api urls, flag in NativeScript Vue?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

The agenda is to use certain flags and a specific api base url for different modes say dev, local and prod in my NativeScript Vue app.
Just like NativeScript angular has environment.[mode].ts files?

I've tried using .env.[mode] files, by referring to VueJs docs
// https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables.com
But this did not favour the scenario.

// Something like this of a config,
module.exports = {
  NODE_ENV: "production",
  ROOT_API: "some api url"
}

The config should be accessible like this
process.env.ROOT_API throughout the app.

Answer (score 2):

Refer the [Pass Environment Variables](https://docs.nativescript.org/performance-optimizations/bundling-with-webpack#nativescript-cli-commands) section in the docs.

> You can also provide environmental variables to the Webpack build:
>
> $ tns build android --bundle --env.development --env.property=value
>   They can be accessed through the env object in the Webpack
>   configuration:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = env => {
    console.dir(env); // { development: true, property: 'value' }
}
```

You may update your `DefinePlugin` something like below,

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "global.TNS_WEBPACK": "true",
            "global.ENV_NAME": JSON.stringify(name),
            "global.ENV_PROPERTY": JSON.stringify(env.property),
            process: undefined,
        }),
```

Now using `global.ENV_PROPERTY` anywhere in your project should be replaced by actual value you pass in command line at compile time.

If you are familar with webpack, you may also configure the `CopyWebpackPlugin` to copy right environment file to your app instead of having variable for each configuration.